# How to Set the response to a state by using this.setState inside a componentDidMount() method

Tags: reactjs

From my react application I made an Ajax request to the spring Mvc controller, got a Jason response from the requested spring controller.

Now am trying to set this response inside my `componentDidMont ()` to a state defined inside the constructor using `this.setState` method using react js.

When I tried to set the state using `this.setState` method I get Type Error:

> Cannot read property 'set State' of undefined error

Please do help me fix this error.

### Course.js

```
import React from "react"; 
import Article from "../components/Article"; 
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Courses extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={items:[]};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("hello");
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/ulearn/rest/course/getAll').then(function (response) {
            this.setState({items: response});
            console.log(response);   
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);   
        });
    }
```

### Render method

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Response - {this.state.items}</div>;
        </div>
    );   
} }
```

Below is the error message:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, defining an anonymous `function` does not automatically inherit the `this` context from the upper scope. So when you define an anonymous `function` callback for your ajax request, `this` becomes `undefined` inside it. Since you are already using ES6 features (like import and class) you can also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with `=>` to overcome the issue. They behave like normal functions, but do not create a new `this` context. So you can simply do this in your `componentDidMount`:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/ulearn/rest/course/getAll')
.then((response) => {
  this.setState({items: response});
  console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: <div>

            {Object.keys(this.state.items).map(function(key) {
                    return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.items[key]}</div>;
                })}
          </div>

Comment: when i tried to iterate the object using the above given code , i got TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined(…)

Comment: how do i fix this ??

Comment: @VijayRNair You need to do the same thing there, replace the `function` definition with an arrow: `Object.keys(this.state.items).map((key) => { return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.items[key]}</div>; })`.

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {instruction, data, status, message}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Courses`.(…)

Comment: {this.state.items.map((item) => {
        <ObjectRow key={item.id} name={item.name} />
    })}      tried with this but got  {this.state.items.map} is not a function error

Comment: @VijayRNair The error is because your `items` is not an array, and thus does not have a `map` method. Have you tried `Object.keys(this.state.items).map((key) => <ObjectRow key={this.state.items[key].id} name={this.state.items[key].name} />)`? If you have further problems, you should probably make another question, since they are not related to your original problem anymore.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ObjectRow is not defined(…)

Comment: how do i fix  the above

Answer (score 0):

As per the error in your comment, as the response above mine beat me to answering your question :) -

You are trying to print out the entire object, try printing out each item individually or adding `.toString()` behind `this.state.items` in your render method. The same thing happens when you try to print `new Date()` for example, it won't let you print out the entire object, but it will let you print a string representation of the object, so `new Date().toString()` would work for example.

Comment: when i tried to iterate the object using the above given code , i got TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined(…)

Comment: The same thing here is happening as per your first problem, you are inside an anonymous function (the mapping function) which has the incorrect reference to this. try:

Comment: `Object.keys(this.state.items).map((key) => { return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.items[key]}</div>).bind(this) }`

Comment: my render method                                                                                                  render() {
    const { query } = this.props.location;
    const { params } = this.props;
    const { article } = params;
    const { date, filter } = query;

    return (
     Object.keys(this.state.items).map((key) => { return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.items[key]}</div>).bind(this) }
    );
  }